# External Drive showing only in system profiler

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, external-disk

I have had a 1TB Western Digital Ultra external hard drive for nearly year.
Out of nowhere it will not show in disk utility but it does show in system profiler. I have a Macbook pro mid 2012 running Yosemite 10.10.1
I have of course tried searching myself but found no clear answers.
I tried verifying the main disk and found nothing wrong. Other external drives work fine with this port and cable. Could it be a hard ware failure? Thanks for the support guys I'm just trying to identify possible causes.

Details given by system profiler:

```
My Passport 0741:

Product ID: 0x0741
Vendor ID:  0x1058  (Western Digital Technologies, Inc.)
Version:    10.22
Serial Number:  575831314139335031333539
Speed:  Up to 5 Gb/sec
Manufacturer:   Western Digital
Location ID:    0x15200000 / 4
Current Available (mA): 900
Current Required (mA):  896
```

Comment: Is it visible on a Windows machine?

Comment: Never used it on a windows machine. The Format is macos journalled and it was working for nearly a year. It suffered no physical damage (no knocks/dropping). I im not so much looking for a fix, more for possible causes.

Comment: WD has some [firmware drivers & utilities](http://support.wdc.com/product/download.asp?groupid=223&lang=en) at their Support site. According to docs: WD Drive Utilities – Register your drive, set drive timer, **run diagnostics** and more using WD Drive Utilities.

Comment: The device listed is actually the USB side of an USB3.0toSATA controller needed to connect the SATA drive to the USB3.0 host controller in your Mac. Your SATA HDD is *not* visible. The HDD is presumably dead or improperly connected to the controller inside the enclosure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If disk utility does not even see it the electronics in the drive may have failed. System Profiler may show a drive there but if disk utility cant access it, well... "Houston we have a problem."

If it IS an external you could try unplugging any other USB devices and/or trying another USB port and possibly even a different USB cable. If you can easily open the case without voiding the warranty you could check cabling there as well. But that might be a waste of time. Drive enclosures are pretty reliable these days.

Failing that you might try a 3rd party disk utility. But I am not sanguine about the prospects. If Disk Utility doesn't even see the drive there is a good possibility nothing else will. It may be time for a new drive.

Comment: Nearly a year later but yes it was a hardware failure.